# Adobe AEM / CQ tutorials

Tags: adobe, aem

I am really interested in learning "Adobe CQ" .
My question is what are all the technologies that I need to learn to understand adobe cq.

Any tutorials on Adobe CQ and related technologies are helpful.

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a developer you can start at http://dev.day.com. CQ is now called as AEM (Adobe Experience Manager).

Technology Stack which makes up CQ:

1. Sling - the MVC framework
   (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SLING/Index)
2. JCR / Jackrabbit
3. OSGi

Google around this and you should be able to get a lot of resources.

Thanks

**EDIT :**

you can go through [helpx adobe site](https://helpx.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/experience-manager.html), from where you can go through small example projects.
For example: [Creating your first Adobe Experience Manager Touch UI component](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-component.html).

It tells you from scratch with step by step guidance and also has zip folder, which you can directly download and upload the package in the crx/de to see what is happening. :)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the technology stack beneath the CQ. I will go through these technologies. I would appreciate if you could point me to  any sample / example projects .

Comment: Hi @Sri, You do need to have a CQ / AEM binary with you to play around it, which is licensed. However if you already have one, further details on developments - component/template details, conventions, articles, videos are available at [ACS AEM Commons](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/) and [AEM Casts](http://aemcasts.com/). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the AEM community page - you will find lots of tutorials and how to articles:

http://helpx.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/experience-manager.html

Answer (score 1):

This will be a big help when developing components-

[Cq5 Widgets Api](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Adobe Gem Sessions](http://dev.day.com/gems) very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can start here. I think this is the best place to start at. I am sharing the link for AEM 6.0. there are similar links for each verion of CQ.

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0.html

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to start developing with Adobe AEM :

1. Use [cqblueprints maven archetype](http://cqblueprints.com/setup/maven.html)
2. [Native adobe maven archetype](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/aem-how-tos/development/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html)

Those 2 ways differ only in module structure, but used plugins are the same.

BTW: Adobe AEM 6.0 has migrated to Jackrabbit Oak-based CRX 3 repository [introduction to OAK](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/introduction-to-oak.html)